# What type of message passing should I use in this situation? GUI sending commands to a Thread; Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets

I have a JFrame that I call mainFrame, it is the main JFrame shown to the user when using my program.

The program creates a Socket to a server and sends messages back and fourth between it and the server.

I am attempting to create a Thread to handle the connection. So when a user clicks "connect" the Thread will setup the Socket and associated input and output streams. I then want the Thread to wait until the JFrame sends it a command, the command just being a String that it should print to the output stream of the Socket. The Thread will send the command, read the response, and then wait for another command.

I figure I could setup a queue that I can "deposit" commands into it and then when the Thread gets around to it, it can pull the first command off of the queue and do with it as it pleases.

Any ideas how to go about that?

Also, currently I pass the argument `this` to the Thread so that it can access a function in the JFrame to print output to a text area. Is this ok to do? Can I allow the Thread to call methods in the JFrame which spawned it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestions:

- The Swing GUI can send text to the Socket, and I don't believe that any additional thread is needed for this since this is non-blocking.
- Yes a separate thread is needed to wait on the Socket and read incoming data. You could use a Scanner perhaps or BufferedReader for this purpose.
- Then send the text from this thread to the GUI perhaps when any new-line chars are encountered. This will need to be done on the EDT, perhaps via the publish/process method pair of a SwingWorker, vs a PropertyChangeListener.
- and yes, a background thread can call methods on the GUI, but always take care to do this on the Swing event thread by placing the code in a Runnable and queuing it on the Swing event queue via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

---

**Edit**
You comment:

> What does "on the EDT" mean?

EDT = the Swing **E**vent **D**ispatch **T**hread, the main Swing thread that performs all Swing drawing and user interactions. If you block this thread, you block all of Swing's display and UI, essentially freezing your program. For details, please see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

> Also say that sending text to the socket was blocking, how might I setup a command queue for it?

I don't understand this question since sending information on the socket *shouldn't* be blocking as far as I understand things.

Comment: What does "on the EDT" mean? // Also say that sending text to the socket was blocking, how might I setup a command queue for it?

Comment: Hmm, Say I have a Thread that calls some blocking method, such as `Socket.accept`. How might I send this Thread a list of commands to perform, in between accepting new data from a socket (it calls socket.accpet in a loop)?

Answer (score 0):

**See this code, but you must implement the parameters yourself:**

```
public class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
    public static final HOST = "www.example.com";
    public static final PORT = 24239;

    private String command;
    private boolean lookahead = false;
    private boolean allowChangeLookahead = true;
    private boolean canRetrieveResult = false;
    Private String result;
    orivate Socket s = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

    public void run() {
        for(;;) { // Infinite loop
            sleep(500); // Avoid low perfomance related problems.

            if(lookahead) {
                allowChangeLookahead = false;

                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    out.println(command);
                    result = in.readLine();
                    canRetrieveResult = true;
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    // Something occured...
                }

                lookahead = false;
                allowChangeLookAhead = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void command(String cmd) {
        command = cmd;

        for(;;) { // Don't worry, not infinite
            if(allowChangeLookahead) {
                lookahead = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized String getResult() {
        for(;;) {
            if(canRetrieveResult) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Meanwhile, in main sequence...**

```
ConnectionThread conThread = new ConnectionThread();
conThread.start();
// ...
// Code of method that responds to command
if(calledCommand) {
    conThread.command(theCommand);
    result = conThread.getResult();
}
```

***That's it! And remember to write the server, ask me if you want help.***

Comment: The `// ...` along with the message, does that imply that the code given in your answer for the main GUI, can it be ran whenever? Such as on button clicks?

Comment: Why doesn't command produce an infinite loop?, and `result` in `ConnectionThread` has no declaration. // So I figure calls to `getResult()` and `command()` block the main GUI until the for loop conditions is satisfied?

Comment: Sorry for the errors. I repaired the `result` problem. And dont worry about the loops, cause server calls have timeouts, so if the asker implements correctly the exception handler, the code will be fast. And remember that the `command()` and `getResult()` methods are synchronized, so everything is verified and situation independent. What happens here is that my code has something like a waiting room, which is the infinite loop of command

Comment: getResult needs a return type too; sorry just OCD.

Comment: @BumSkeeter Repaired. Thanks for the note.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. It freezes up the GUI but still writes to the system output, if I comment out the for loop in the run method of the ConnectionThread it will run the command, but then I loose the connection...

Comment: @BumSkeeter That is because you must handle correctly the SDT (Swing Dispatch Thread). Learn about it and your program (with my code) will be as fast as the the light.

Comment: For the connection problem I edited (I expect finally) the code.

Comment: I am using SwingUtilities when having the ConnectionThread write to the GUI's text areas as @Hover Craft Full Of Eels suggested above. Do I need to start the Thread in any special way? // The connection is lost because I do not have the ConnectionThread loop and it returns, But it does not freeze the GUI, if I have it loop the GUI freezes but the Thread still runs fine. The Thread has no interaction with the GUI other than sending runnables to the dispatch Thread.

Comment: @BumSkeeter You MUST use conThread.start() and NOT conThread.run() because run doesnt have the magical trick that really creates an independent thread. If thats not the case, reply with more info.